# jquery datepicker - Any idea what controls this action?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I've got this datepicker (although it's doing the exact same thing on a multiselect dropdown control that also relies on jquery):

[image]

As you'll notice, only the right arrow is showing.  That's because I am hovering over it.

Essentially, none of the arrows in any of my jquery controls will show until they are hovered over.

Does anyone know which CSS class fixes this?  I think it's ui-icon because when I putzed with it then they didn't even show on hover, but I can't figure out the right setting.

My current ui-icon looks like this:

```
.ui-icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
```

And I changed it to this with no luck:

```
.ui-icon {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I may even be barking up the wrong tree, but when I put that second block in I couldn't see any buttons at all, not even on hover so I'm just assuming the magic happens there.

Comment: No console errors? In the developer console turn the `:hover` feature on and check the CSS when you're hovering on the icon, copy paste that CSS for the regular class (when not hovered)

Comment: When you use display: block, you set the button to be sensitive to its content. In your case, the content seems to be empty so just specify width and height ;-) like 15px to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was this little devil:

```
.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    /*  Default color of any arrows/icons on any jquery controls */
    background-image: url("../Images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png");
}
```

which I have now added a comment to in my code.  Discovered that my sample code came from a theme that included a few colors that my app didn't, and so a couple of the URLs were pointing to files I didn't have.  This particular CSS entry deals with those default arrows.